# Tomcat fails to load Struts 2 (exception starting filter struts2)

Tags: eclipse, exception, tomcat, filter, struts2

I am using the Eclipse (Java EE / Helios) IDE, struts2, and Tomcat 7.0.6. My web application was working fine yesterday, but some unknown change has killed it and the server starts but no longer functions correctly. When trying to view a .jsp file, I am greeted with the message:

> description The requested resource ()
>   is not available.

(if it even decides to put up that error at all)

A look in the console gives me this error when I try to start the Tomcat server via Eclipse and load the 'Add.jsp' page:

```
...
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 2, 2011 1:38:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.6
Feb 2, 2011 1:38:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5040)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5035)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Feb 2, 2011 1:38:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Feb 2, 2011 1:38:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/StrutsTest] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 2, 2011 1:38:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
...
```

This appears to now be a problem with all of the struts2 applications I have made previously. Restarting Eclipse and/or my PC doesn't seem to help.

Here is a copy of my Web.xml (which is very similar, throughout each project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Development Environments</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Add.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I've tried updating certain .jars in my classpath to the latest version (although I didn't expect that to work). Does anyone know what might be going wrong? I'm happy to give more information if you know what else is needed.

Comment: It looks like you are missing the `servlet-api` JAR. That should be packaged with Tomcat.

Comment: I have 'servlet-api.jar' in the C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.6\lib directory, along with other .jar files (catalina.jar, jasper.jar, tomcat-api.jar, catalina-ant.jar, etc)

Shoult the servlet-api.jar be in a different directory? Or should I be including it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I had to add  a path to servlet-api in the apache lib folder. Weird but after that it worked

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this sort of thing several times with Tomcat/Eclipse where basic classes suddenly seem to disappear. I think that Eclipse/Tomcat just get themselves confused at times. It seems to happen more often if I've left the server running with auto-deploy enabled and I make a lot of small changes.

When this happens I shut down the server. I run "clean" on my project and then clean on the tomcat server and clean the server work directory. When I restart the server everything starts working again.

Answer (score 0):

First, try checking the Tomcat server log to see if Tomcat is experiencing some type of fatal error upon start up.

The exception indicates that the servlet API JAR cannot be found, however you appear to have the JAR in the correct location.

Are you running the application from Eclipse? If so, perhaps Eclipse is not starting Tomcat properly. What happens if you try to start Tomcat manually and deploy your application without Eclipse?

**Update**

Since the behavior was consistent whether Eclipse started Tomcat or you started it manually, we can rule out Eclipse as part of the problem.

I would try the following:

- Try deploying a simple servlet project or even a JSP — it may be helpful to know if *anything* runs
- Re-install Tomcat — you mentioned this happened abruptly recently, something may have happened to the Tomcat installation

Comment: I did not see a fatal error in the logs, so I moved all the logs to an old/ directory, then I started up Tomcat manually using startup.bat (I'm on Windows, and I've been using Eclipse). I then used a web browser to browse to: http://localhost:8080/DevEnvironments/Add.jsp, where it said, "description The requested resource (/DevEnvironments/Add.jsp) is not available." (I'm not sure if any additional steps are needed when deploying an app). The newly created log files have no errors, but I pasted them anyway: http://pastebin.com/K5mk0HLe

Comment: I've revised my answer based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum to run a helloworld kind Struts2 app would require these jars.

- struts2-core-*.jar
- xwork-core-*.jar
- ognl-*.jar
- commons-logging-*.jar
- commons-io*.jar
- commons-lang*.jar
- commons-fileupload*.jar
- freemarker-*.jar
- javaassist-*.jar

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all jars including commons-lang3-x.x

You can find missing jar by looking the apache logs like:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils**
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
... 55 more