# Switched to Eclipse Juno and Filter class not found

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, web.xml, eclipse-juno

I'm trying to get a project running in the server in Springsource Tool Suite (based on Eclipse Juno.)  It used to run in an earlier version of Eclipse.  It's a maven project, and it builds fine from the command line.

The problem I'm seeing right now is that it can't find a filter class referenced in `web.xml` though in the previous release of Eclipse, it had no problem finding this class.  The `web.xml` filter clause looks like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.foo.bar.dao.hibernate.HibernateSessionFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

When I try to run it in the internal Tomcat 6 server, I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter hibernateFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.foo.bar.dao.hibernate.HibernateSessionFilter
```

When I run `jar tf app.war | grep HibernateSessionFilter` the class is there in the war file:

```
$ jar tf imagewar.war | grep HibernateSessionFilter
WEB-INF/classes/com/foo/bar/dao/hibernate/HibernateSessionFilter.class
```

Perhaps it doesn't belong in WEB-INF/classes?

As I said, this app used to build and run in the internal server.  What do I need to do with Juno to tell it where my app's classes are?

Comment: I don't understand what Eclipse has to do with the problem. You manage to generate a war file (so everything is fine regarding Eclipse), but you get an exception when deploying this war file to Tomcat, right? So the problem is a problem with the war file or the web.xml, right? Where is the HibernateSessionFilter.class file inside the war file?

Comment: Any idea or clues in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880331/tomcat-fails-to-load-struts-2-exception-starting-filter-struts2 ?

Comment: Eclipse has a server tab.  It is use to make it easy to deploy and test your webapp in Tomcat (or other server).  The only thing that has changed is the version of Eclipse; I'm now using Juno.  And with that change, the war file no longer starts up properly in this server tab.  When I build the app via the command line (mvn package) the war file is correct, as before, because the source hasn't changed.  The class is in the war file, as I said in the problem explanation.

Comment: @VonC, I don't think that question addresses it.  Note that the class i'm trying to load is one of my own.  It just happens to override a class related to Hibernate.  For whatever reason, Tomcat can no longer see a compiled class file.

Comment: In your question you mention that it can't find com.foo.bar.dao.hibernate.HibernateSessionFilter, but the compiled jar doesn't contain that class, it contains com.sodapopsoftware.imagewar.dao.hiberate.HibernateSessionFilter.  Should those be the same?

Comment: They're the same. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deploy through Eclipse, you should check if Eclipse deployed your application correctly - Eclipse does not deploy using a WAR file, rather it copies right into the appservers webapp location the necessary files.

Sometimes though Eclipse messes up with this - there are known bugs of WTP for deployment.

You should check the 
    .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core- 
folder and its subfolders (each subfolder represents a registered server instance).

Sometimes you need to completeley erase the deployment in webapps and redeploy in Eclipse. It's magic but it works.

The one thing you should NOT check: your WAR file: Eclipse does not deploy from the WAR file. Please check the deployed classes first.

And a last hint: If you are using m2e for Maven, you should install the m2e-wtp plugin for WTP support.

Comment: You definitely cleared up the whole war-not-war thing.  I'm still having a lot of trouble getting the project to build and launch, though.  Seems like you have to tell Eclipse a lot more about where files are in Juno.  Previous version I just imported the Maven project and boom, it'd launch in the server tab.  No muss, no fuss.